# How to check certain bytes at an offset and set checkboxes accordingly

Tags: c#

I need to know how to check bytes at an offset. I am using strings for hexes i.e `string hexcode1 = "0000A0E1";` and the offset is `int offset1 = 30030;` how would i check if at offset1 it has hexcode1. please note I do know about filestreams and binarywriters/readers but do not know how to use them with strings. that is partly what i need help with.

Comment: Are you referring to bit-wise operations?

Comment: what offset stands for? Offset in bits?

Comment: strings can not be presented in *that* way, do you mean something like string hexcode1 = "0000A0E1" ?

Comment: i am not really sure what that is @neil (new to C#) i have looked into converting strings to byte arrays but it still doesn't solve my problem of checking bytes at certain offsets

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "checking bytes at certain offsets" and why you are using strings?

Comment: @Oded I am using strings so people can easily customize the code and i mean check if at file offset 0x30030 there is the hex code 00 00 A0 E1

Comment: Where are these values coming from?

Comment: @user1341789 I mean, you have 0x01FF and 0xFFF0 and you want to end up with 0x01F0, except rather than do this on numbers or bytes, you want to do it on a byte per byte basis in a string?

Comment: @Oded a filestream with a file opened in if that is what you mean

Comment: This is why code examples are useful.

Comment: @Neil huh? where are those numbers coming from?

Comment: @user1341789 they're examples.  I'm trying to understand your problem outside the context of your singlular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Using a binary reader, offset the file, then read the byte and convert to string, to compare against your current string.

```
        file = File.Open(myFileLocation); 
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file);

        string hexcode1 = "0000A0E1";
        int offset1 = 20334;

        file.Seek(offset1, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        String byteRead = br.ReadByte().ToString();

        mycheckbox.Checked = (hexcode1.Equals(byteRead));
```

Comment: apparently setchecked and .equals do not exist. do i need to change .NET framework?

Comment: Edited my answer to use the correct method to setting checked. Also, I accidently missed the capital E on Equals. It should exist.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the bytes at a certain position in a stream you can simply use the [`Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position.aspx) property of the `Stream` and start reading as much as you want.

If the stream supports seeking, you can use the [`Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) method.

You can parse a string into an integer using [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) and pass the resulting value to either `Position` or `Seek`.

Comment: thanks but how do I check that at the offset the bytes = hexstring1 and then set a checkbox to checked (to me it is harder than it sounds)

Comment: @user1341789 - Do you know how to read the bytes? Read the documentation of `string.Format` too. You really need to start reading documentation.

Comment: i know how to read bytes but don't know what to do after that

Comment: if your representing them as string.  Why not just do `mycheckbox.setChecked(hexcode1.equals(offset1));`

Comment: @Doomsknight wouldn't that set the checkbox only if the 2 strings were the same?

Comment: @user1341789 Yes. but your question shows that you have the two bytes you want to compare in string representation? Oh woops, that is an string of an integer offset not a byte. Forget what I said. Why is your offset a string and not an int :/ had me confused

Comment: @Doomsknight my fault, it meant to be an int but my brain was dead. will edit post now